# DropDownCheckBoxes doesn't bind with DataSet values

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

I'm using `DropDownCheckBoxes` `CodePlex` control. This works fine with the below code

```
var t = new string[20];
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
t[i] = "Test   " + i.ToString();

DropDownCheckBoxes1.DataSource = t;
DropDownCheckBoxes1.DataBind();
```

But when I use the same logic and get the value from `DataSet`, it doesn't work. `DropDownCheckBoxes1` is not loaded with any values. Please let me know what is wrong here. I know we can reduce the code here and directly assign `DropDownCheckBoxes1.DataSource = q.Distinct()` but nothing is working for me

```
DataSet ds = GetTheData("Jan 2014");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

var q = from a in dt.AsEnumerable()
        where a.Field<string>("SomeColumn1") == "Jan 2014"
        select a.Field<string>("SomeColumn2");

var s = q.Distinct().ToList();
var years = new string[s.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
    years[i] = s[i];

DropDownCheckBoxes1.DataSource = years;
DropDownCheckBoxes1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataSet ds = GetTheData("Jan 2014");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

var q = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.Field<String>("SomeColumn1") == "Jan 2014")
                         .Select(a => a.Field<String>("SomeColumn2"));

DropDownCheckBoxes1.DataSource = q;
DropDownCheckBoxes1.DataBind();
```

Comment: how are you getting AsDataView on q? I see we can use this only on DataTable? i get this option only on dt.AsDataView()

Comment: What if you cast it to EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> like i did?

Comment: Errored with **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<string>' to 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>'**

Comment: Sorry, it was EnumerableRowCollection<String>

Comment: Again, q.AsDataView is not valid now. Please do try it once & then suggest.

Comment: I tested it with that code. It works fine with a datatable created on the fly. See my code here: http://hpics.li/7d44f0d and the result: http://hpics.li/6f83ba0

Comment: I got to know what is wrong. the custom control DropDowncheckboxes from codeplex uses Page.ClientScript and even I was using Page.ClientScript at GetTheData() function. This was causing issue. I commented out my Page.ClientScript and even my code started working. I'll mark your answer for the effort. Thanks much for the help.